# ABA RTN with valid checksum but is test only

Tags: web-services, web-applications, checksum

Not sure where to post this question... I'd like to know if test only ABA Routing and Transit Numbers (RTN) exist. In otherwords, the number will pass the checksum test, but it is for application testing only and will never be assigned to a financial institution by the registrar that manages the ABA RTNs.

I'm enhancing a web application that provides merchant services via credit card to also support echecks. For credit card test purposes I use VISA number 4111-1111-1111-1111 since that has been flagged as one of VISA's test card numbers and no credit charge will actually occur.

Is there an analogous number identified for ABA TRNs by its registrar? If not, does anyone know of one of the ABA RTNs that are available for future use and still not assigned (and unlikely to be assigned, kinda like using all 9 for SSN)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did get an answer... What I ended up doing is using one of the reserved TRNs, specifically 440000000.

Answer (score 1):

The first two digits of 13-20, 33-60, 73-79, 81-99 are all not assigned per the [Routing Number Policy, Section IV. Routing Number Structure (page 3)](http://www.accuity.com/PageFiles/255/ROUTING_NUMBER_POLICY.pdf).

Any 9 digit number that passes the CRC and starts with any numbers in the above ranges are pretty much guaranteed to be not usable in the real world.

411411411 is what I use for testing when I'm worried about leaking out to the real world.  Otherwise 123123123 is easy to remember too.